# TYPO3 10.4 sometimes page rendering is very slow

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

System:
TYPO3: 10.4.22
PHP: 7.4.30
Apache 2.4.46
Windows Server 2019
X64

Hello!
I have the issue that sometimes the page rendering is absolutely slow. I added a simple page and "normal" page generation is about 200ms. But about each 10th load of the page it is very slow - about 20 seconds.

I checked the issue in the Admin Panel and if I look at the TS-Tree I have a very big value in the Script Start row (e.g. +21075 for a 21048ms run vs. +235 for a 205ms run).

I checked the performance (memory, network, cpu of the server itself and everything looks good). I did a test when no one else was working (it is a intranet installation) so I was the only one hitting the page and run into the same issue. If I do a reload after a slow load I get a fast load immediately.

Any ideas what is happing on these slow runs?

Thank you

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Try '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'

(in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php, 'DB' => 'Connections' =>            'Default' => 'host')

Comment: Thank you but we already use 127.0.0.1 for DB Connection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an old File Storage Setting. The file storage was configured as local filesystem to a directory which was a symlink to a fileshare on another server. This server was switched off. The file storage was not in use anymore but the record in TYPO3 still existed and was set to "online". I have no clue why it slew down the page loading only each 5 or 8 time....